# which distribution to expect for interval counts

Tags: distributions

It is my first question here and I am not a statistian. So - I am sorry for any mistake - please correct me.

I have data from measuring a feature of a number of entities (continious data). As I don't know which distribution to expect, the feature range has been divided into fixed bins. For each independet experiment, I retrieve the entity counts for each bin. That means for each bin, I have as many counts as experiments.

Example:

```
Experiment 1 - Bin 1 - 20
Experiment 2 - Bin 1 - 19
Experiment 3 - Bin 1 - 22

Experiment 1 - Bin 2 - 5
Experiment 2 - Bin 2 - 9
Experiment 3 - Bin 2 - 7
```

Looking at the counts of a single bin: Which distribution would I expect?

Answer (score 1):

Within an experiment, an observation can only end up in one bin.

If the observations are independent before you bin them, you would look at a multinomial distribution for each experiment.

That is considering experiment $i$, then if the count in bin $j$ is $X_{i,j}$, then $(X_{i,1},X_{i,2},X_{i,3},...,X_{i,n})$ would be multinomial with parameters $n_i$ (the total number of values in experiment $i$) and the set of population proportions for that experiment.

If you focus on a single bin (compared to all others), that would be binomial.

If you consider the set of counts in the bins for all experiments, then if the counts are independent across experiments you'd have an independent collection of multinomials.

If you consider the set of counts in one bin over all experiments, that would be a collection of independent binomial observations.

Comment: I think - I am interested in the last point you mentioned. I am just not sure whether I can use that information for my final problem :-) I might need to reformulate my problem...

Comment: added a sentence I neglected to add before.

Comment: Question: Instead of a multinomial (first case you mentioned) - could it be a hypergeometric distribution (as it is without replacement...)?

Comment: Possibly hypergeometric, though nothing in the question suggested it to me. Could you describe the situation more explicitly (in your question)?

Comment: Let's compare one experiment to this: Within a fish tank 100 fish grew up. I take a big net, get as much fish as possible and measure their length. Then I put each fish into one of five bins according to their length. (10-15cm, 15-20cm, ...) From my prior knowledge, I have a certain expectation how the fishes should be distributed (20% in the first bin, 40% in the second bin, ...). And I would like to test, if the acutal count fit to that. Does it make it a bit more clear?
(I will put it into muy questions if it helps at all)

Comment: Is the number of each kind in the tank known in advance? (Less important: Does the net definitely hold less than 100?)

Comment: No, it's unknown. Imagine: All fishes are of the same kind and the same age. Just the growth differs over time.
Second question: It's very unlikely that you get all fish in the net (but it's not impossible

Comment: Assuming we treat the categories as existing from the start but unobserved at the time, since you don't know the numbers in the categories in the tank, I don't think you can treat it as hypergeometric (or multivariate hypergeometric for more than two categories). If you condition on the total in the net it's still multinomial (binomial for two groups). So even with the new information, I believe my original answer.applies.